# sending image or video or audio with sms data

Tags: android, video, sms, mms

I am trying to make an application where I can get videos from my webserver download it to a users phone, and they have the option to mms it to someone. I have found that you can do this via the native mms app  on your phone but I want to know if it is possible to be able to send it directly from my app... I cannot come across anything AT all and it is driving me insane.. I even tried just sending the image through regular send string sms

```
                           //SmsMessage []msgs = null;
                        // SmsManager sms   = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        // sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

where the message paramter was an image object, but it  just crashes the app..

doe anyone have any clue on how to send image/video/audio?

Answer (score 0):

See this blog http://androidbridge.blogspot.de/2011/03/how-to-send-mms-programmatically-in.html or another option would be to use a third party API like Twilio or this API from AT&T https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=12700029

Comment: do you know how "cross phone/android os vers" this is?

Comment: Not sure sorry. The APIs from Twilio and AT&T are REST though so will work on any platform.

Comment: i looked at them.. so it seems you have to send the image/voice/video to their service and then they send it?... there's no way to directly send to another phone p2p?